# R ggplot2 add a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

As described, I want to add a legend to my graph.

```
nice_plot <-  ggplot() +
geom_line(data = plot_dataframe_SD1, mapping = aes(x = XValues, y = YValues_SD1), color = "blue") +
geom_line(data = plot_dataframe_SD2, mapping = aes(x = XValues, y = YValues_SD2), color = "green") +
xlim(1, 2) +
ylim(1, 5) +
xlab("Standarard Deviation") +
ylab("AV") +
scale_fill_identity(name = 'the fill', guide = 'legend',labels = c('m1')) +
scale_colour_manual(name = 'the colour', 
                    values =c('blue'='blue','green'='green'), labels = c('c2','c1'))
```

This is my code so far, btut it won't output a legend.
I also don't get an error message.

What is wrong with the code or what do I miss out?

Comment: It would be great if you add `plot_dataframe_SD1` and `plot_dataframe_SD2` using `dput()` to reproduce your issue!

Comment: Try using `draw_key_*()`. Check out [this reference guide](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html#section-guides-axes-and-legends).

Comment: @Luma move the `color = "green"` and `color = "blue"` _inside_ your `aes` calls.

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron !
Now it works :)